# PHPMail - can I send two unique emails

Tags: php

I'm using PHPMailer to successfully send an email upon a webform submission (so just using basic post data, no mysql databases or any lookups).

What I need to do is send two seperate emails, one version for the customer and the other for a customer service agent - so that when a user completes a webform, they will receive a 'marketing' version of the email, whilst the customer service agent will receive an email just containing the details submitted by the user.

See below what im using at the moment, but not sure how to best implement to send the secoind email? It presently fails and the script exits after sending only one email.

```
$body = ob_get_contents();
$to = 'removed';
$email = 'removed';
$fromaddress = "removed";
$fromname = "removed";

require("phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = $fromaddress;
$mail->FromName = $fromname ;
$mail->AddAddress("email@example.com");


$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  =  "Subject";
$mail->Body     =  $body;
$mail->AltBody  =  "This is the text-only body";

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $recipient = 'email@example.com';
    $subject = 'Contact form failed';
    $content = $body;   
  mail($recipient, $subject, $content, 
    "From: mail@yourdomain.com\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nX-Mailer: DT_formmail");
  exit;

}


//Send the customer version
  $mail=new PHPMailer();
  $mail->SetFrom('email', 'FULLNAME');
  $mail->AddAddress($mail_vars[2], 'sss');

  $mail->Subject    = "Customers email";

  $mail->MsgHTML("email body here");

  //$mail->Send();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the customer version you are not setting the email's properties the same way you are in the first. For example you use `$mail->From = $fromaddress;` in the first and  `$mail->SetFrom('email', 'FULLNAME');` in the second.

Because you instantiated a new `$mail=new PHPMailer();` you need to set the properties again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just bailing out with a useless "something didn't work" message, why not have PHPMailer **TELL** you what the problem is?

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
   $error = $mail->ErrorInfo;
   echo "Mail failed with  error: $error";
}
```